# Add counter as suffix to all files in subfolders

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this problem with renaming 50,000 files, separated to numerous folders. the problem is that the original sequential naming is all massed up because some file were deleted, so the count jumps from let's say *0005 to *0007.

I want to rename all the files in all subfolders, so that the suffix will be a 4 digit number, based on the current order of the files. Most importantly I want the counter the restart in each folder.

I have one working script that renames the files according putting a general name and then the folder name and last the current file name.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test -Filter *.tif -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { 'IL-TRUM'+'_'+$_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.name}
```

All I need to do is to add another counter at the end!

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Good luck!

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the counter to restart in each folder you need to separate folder recursion from enumerating/renaming the TIFF files in each folder. Try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\test' -Recurse | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer
} | ForEach-Object {
    $cnt = 0
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Filter '*.tif' | ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ("IL-TRUM_{0}_{1}_{2:d4}{3}" -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name, $cnt, $_.Extension)
        $cnt++
    }
}
```